# Opening compare editor results inside a wizard page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my custom plugin I am trying open compare result inside a wizard page but they always open in an editor or as a new dialog.

I am overriding `setVisible(booolean)`method, so as soon as wizard page is visible I am opening compare editor using `CompareUI.openCompareEditor()`call, but this opens up a new editor in the background.

Is it possible to open compare editor results inside a wizard page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing support for this.

You could read the source of the dialog that is displayed by `openCompareDialog.openCompareDialog` - this is `org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareDialog`.
It looks like it might be possible to do the same thing in a wizard page without using internal classes by adapting what that dialog does.